# Rails shuffle form input data in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have five form inputs as text, and basically I want to randomly show them on each page load for the user. Right now it shows up as 1-5, but I want it random everytime.

**show.html.erb**

```
<p class="question-answer-choice"><%= @post.answer_choice %></p>
<p class="question-answer-choice"><%= @post.answer_choice_2 %></p>
<p class="question-answer-choice"><%= @post.answer_choice_3 %></p>
<p class="question-answer-choice"><%= @post.answer_choice_4 %></p>
<p class="question-answer-choice"><%= @post.answer_choice_5 %></p>
```

I'm trying the .sample method(?) on the form input variables, but it doesn't do anything or show up in the view.

posts_controller.rb

```
...
@randomize_posts = ["@post.answer_choice", "@post.answer_choice_2", "@post.answer_choice_3", "@post.answer_choice_4", "@post.answer_choice_5"].sample
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the shuffle method on `@randomize_posts` then use that in the view

posts_controller.rb

```
@randomize_posts = [
  @post.answer_choice,
  @post.answer_choice_2,
  @post.answer_choice_3,
  @post.answer_choice_4,
  @post.answer_choice_5
].shuffle
```

show.html.erb

```
<% @randomize_posts.each do |answer_choice| %>
  <p class="question-answer-choice"><%= answer_choice %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I get this error: undefined method `answer_choice' for nil:NilClass, in the controller.

Also, wouldn't the show.html.erb code only shuffle any answer choice thats only called "answer_choice", and not those with _2, _3 etc added at the end?

Comment: Is answer_choice not a method on @post? also have you loaded @post before calling the method on it? I see in your array they were just strings which is probably why you didn't get the error before. The shuffle method will randomise all elements in the array irrespective of what they are

Comment: By this you mean putting it under the "def show" in the posts.controller right? What does it mean to "be a method on @post"?

Comment: I meant i assume you can call answer_choice on @post

Answer (score 1):

You could use select to get each attribute in your object that match with answer in its name, and then get the values, like:

```
@randomize_posts = @post.attributes.select { |name, _| name =~ /answer/ }.values.shuffle
```

Then in your view:

```
<% @randomize_posts.each do |answer| %>
  <p class="question-answer-choice"><%= answer %></p>
<% end %>
```

As you have your `@post` object, you can access its attributes by using `@post.attributes`, this would give you a hash like:

```
@post.attributes
=> {
 "id"=>1,
 "answer_choice"=>"answer_choice",
 "answer_choice2"=>"answer_choice2",
 ... # Plus other additional attributes
```

Having a hash then you can use select, to "filter" over those attributes where the name matches with the word answer (the name is the hash key, and is the only thing needed, so you can avoid using the value and that's why I used `_`). So you get something like:

```
@post.attributes.select { |name, _| name =~ /answer/ }
# => { "answer_choice"=>"answer_choice", "answer_choice2"=>"answer_choice2" ... }
```

So from the hash you can get only the values as hash.values:

```
["answer_choice", "answer_choice2" ...]
```

And you get an array, and now you can use `shuffle` on it.